# Socket Exception error in android emulator

Tags: flutter, apache, dart, laravel-8

i'm new to laravel and flutter, so i configured my laravel backend successfully. I test the API using postman and posted to the database successfully, now when I try to post the data using androind emulator, I kept receiving the error (SocketException. connection refused (OS error. connection refused, ernno=111) address= 127.0.0.1, port keeps changing)

**My API client is as follows**

```
import 'package:myapp/utils/app_constants.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class ApiClient extends GetConnect implements GetxService{
  late String token;
  final String appBaseUrl;

  late Map<String, String> _mainHeaders;

  ApiClient({required this.appBaseUrl}){
    baseUrl = appBaseUrl;
    timeout = const Duration(seconds: 30);
    token = AppConstants.TOKEN;
    _mainHeaders ={
      'Content-type':'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };
  }

  void updateHeader(String token){
    _mainHeaders ={
      'Content-type':'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };

  }
  Future<Response> getData(String uri,)async{
    try{
      Response response =await get(uri);
      return response;
    }catch(e){
      return Response(statusCode: 1, statusText: e.toString());
    }
  }
  Future<Response>postData(String uri, dynamic body) async {
    print(body.toString());
    try{
      Response response = await post(uri, body, headers: _mainHeaders);
      return response;
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return Response (statusCode: 1, statusText: e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

**AppConstants.dart**

```
class AppConstants{
  static const String APP_NAME ="RideSharing";
  static const int APP_VERSION = 1;

  static const String BASE_URL ="http://127.0.0.1:8000/";

  //auth end points
  static const String REGISTRATION_URI ="api/dv/auth/register";

  static const String TOKEN = "RideToken";

}
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Zel.png)

Comment: search some other website on chrome in the emulator. Is that working?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the server locally and using the Android emulator, then your server endpoint should be 10.0.2.2:8000 instead of localhost:8000 as AVD uses 10.0.2.2 as an alias to your host loopback interface (i.e) localhost.

Or

behalf on localhost add your currunt IP address
As an example (I'm on linux environment)

```
sudo apt install net-tools
ifconfig
```

[image]

simply replaced "localhost" in flutter app http requests. And it will worked.

Comment: i had spent hours trying to solve the issue and finally I found it